# get/put steps to microsoft's ToDo tasks via api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When fetching the list of tasks I have in the App using the graphs api, I am not able to see the steps of a task.

I also can't find anything useful in the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlooktask-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

I am calling this route (using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks?$count=true&$filter=status ne 'completed'`

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft ToDo API doesn't support:

- Task's subtasks aka steps
- My Day
- Tasks order

So all we can do is to wait until MS API team delivers it. Perhaps, never.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small typo in your query.

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks?count=true&filter=status eq 'completed'
```

Comment: How is that a typo? I am searching for the tasks which are **_not_** finished